# "mount -t zfs -fw" can't mount a ZFS volume 100% of the time

Tags: partition, freebsd, zfs

Actually I have installed my daily work FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE system on the ZFS disk ada0 :

```
=>       40  976773088  ada0  GPT  (466G)

         40     532480     1  efi  (260M)

     532520       1024     2  freebsd-boot  (512K)

     533544        984        - free -  (492K)

     534528    4194304     3  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)

    4728832  972044288     4  freebsd-zfs  (464G)

  976773120          8        - free -  (4.0K)
```

instead,on the disk ada2 I have installed most of the services and applications that I have installed on the drive ada0 and sometimes I switch to this system (it's the same 13.1-RELEASE,but on a UFS2 fs) :

```
=>       40  625142368  ada2  GPT  (298G)

         40     532480     1  efi  (260M)

     532520  616030208     2  freebsd-ufs  (294G)

  616562728    8388608     3  freebsd-swap  (4.0G)

  624951336     191072        - free -  (93M)
```

sometimes,when I'm on the system installed on the disk ada2,I want to mount the root partition of the system installed on /dev/ada0p4 (FreeBSD-ZFS on the disk ada0) and to do that,I use these commands :

```
zfs mount -a
mount -t zfs -fw zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b /mnt/freebsd-zfs
```

what's the problem ? the problem is that it works a lot of time,but not everytime and I don't understand the reason. Sometimes,like now,it gives the error below. Is there a more secure way to mount the ZFS partition so that it works 100% ? thanks.

```
mount: zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE : I tried this,it almost worked,but unfortunately I don't see every file and folder stored on the disk :

```
# zpool import -f -R /mnt/freebsd-zfs zroot 
ls /mnt/freebsd-zfs tmp   
usr    var    zroot
```

this also didn't work :

```
# zpool import -f -R /mnt/freebsd-zfs zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b 
cannot import 'zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b': no such pool available
```

I want mount the path "zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b" :

```
# sudo zfs list

NAME                      USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT  

zroot                     216G   230G       96K  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/zroot
zroot/ROOT                203G   230G       96K  none
zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-a   512K   230G     43.4G  /mnt/freebsd-zfs
zroot/ROOT/31-03-2022-b   203G   230G      175G  /mnt/freebsd-zfs
zroot/tmp                10.6M   230G     10.6M  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/tmp
zroot/usr                11.7G   230G       96K  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/usr
zroot/usr/home            192K   230G      192K  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/usr/home
zroot/usr/ports          8.33G   230G     8.33G  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/usr/ports
zroot/usr/src            3.36G   230G     3.36G  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/usr/src
zroot/var                1.26G   230G       96K  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var
zroot/var/audit            96K   230G       96K  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var/audit
zroot/var/crash          1.11G   230G     1.11G  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var/crash
zroot/var/log            3.59M   230G     3.59M  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var/log
zroot/var/mail            130M   230G      130M  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var/mail
zroot/var/tmp            18.1M   230G     18.1M  /mnt/freebsd-zfs/var/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `altroot` property on the pool to `/mnt/freebsd-zfs` **before** importing it or `zfs mount`-ing any of the datasets.

From `man zpoolprops`:

> `altroot`
>
> Alternate root directory.  If set, this directory is prepended to any
> mount points within the pool.  This can be used when examining an unknown
> pool where the mount points cannot be trusted, or in an alternate boot
> environment, where the typical paths are not valid.
>
> `altroot` is not a persistent property.  It is valid only while the system
> is up.
>
> Setting `altroot` defaults to using `cachefile=none`, though this may be
> overridden using an explicit setting.

Note that it says "**not a persistent property**".  You'll need to do this every time you want to import the pool and mount its datasets into your ufs2 boot environment.